# \fbox around multiple \includegraphics

Tags: floats, boxes

I am working on a figure like this,

```
\begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a.png}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b.png}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{c.png}
\end{figure}
```

and would like to draw a box around the figures.
I tried

```
\begin{figure}
      \fbox{%
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a.png}
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b.png}
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{c.png}
      }
\end{figure}
```

but then all the figures appear on one line (and, therefore, out of the page).
Is there a simple fix to this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Using `center` inside `figure` is not good practice, because it adds unwanted space. Better using `\centering` instead of the `center` environment. It's not relevant for your problem, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only adding a space and then relying on line breaking to put the figures on separate lines, and there is no line breaking in an fbox, you could do

```
 \fbox{\parbox{.8\textwidth}{% or whatever you need
         \centering
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a.png}

          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b.png}

          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c.png}
      }}
```

You need the `\fbox` to be a bit narrower that `\textwidth` to leave room for the border. If you want it to fit exactly use

```
\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}
```

Comment: @Rastapopoulos sorry fixed the missing `{` :-)